# Using POST in jQuery with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I the site is on the following URL `localhost:xxxx/VnosPrijavnica/Predmeti/123456`, where the `VnosPrijavnica` is the controller, `Predmeti` is an action in the controller, and `123456` is an optional param (everything is defined correctly in Global.asax). The site loads fine, just when it comes to jQuery's `$.post()` I encoutered a problem. The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$("#predmet").change(function () {
    $("#predmet option[value='prazen']").hide();
    $.post("/VnosPrijavnica/PoisciRoke", $("#kriteriji").serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#roki").html(data);
    });
});
```

The `$.post()` never executes. I noticed if I change the URL to `localhost:xxxx/VnosPrijavnica` this piece of jQuery code works as intended. The question is what must I modify in the jQuery code that it will work with the first URL as it does in the second?

Comment: Try checking your action method names and parameters. Maybe the second URL name that works has the correct method parameters to take the POST request, where as the first one doesn't? I don't think there's anything from a jQuery perspective that's stopping this working.

Comment: I think the parameters are ok, as I said if I rework the code and this is called just from localhost/VnosPrijavnica everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';

$("#predmet").change(function () {
    $("#predmet option[value='prazen']").hide();
    $.post(baseUrl + "/VnosPrijavnica/PoisciRoke", $("#kriteriji").serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#roki").html(data);
    });
});
```